# how can I use teams-for-linux as default teams application

Tags: microsoft-teams

I am using following teams application in 22.04 LTS Desktop.

```
teams-for-linux               1.4.12                      527    latest/stable    ismaelmartinez
```

when I click teams request in Thunderbird, walc (whatsapp client), html based email services, slack or any app,  it does not open teams-for-linux app. It opens a www page in firefox or brave

Is there any way to force to use teams-for-linux app for teams meetings ?

Best Regards

Comment: Can you go through the comments here? https://github.com/IsmaelMartinez/teams-for-linux/issues/675

Comment: If you have more questions, you can talk to community members here too: https://matrix.to/#/#teams-for-linux_community:gitter.im

Comment: @JijoJoseph  thx, will check URLs